# Website shows different content on HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: http, ubuntu, redirect, https, openlitespeed

I have a WordPress site on OpenLiteSpeed using Google Cloud Platform and I just somehow managed to get an SSL for my new domain and now the site shows different content on HTTP and HTTPS

Server Info:

1. Runs on: Google Compute Engine
2. Version: 6
3. Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04
4. Package contents: WordPress 5.5 , PHP 7.4 , OpenLiteSpeed 1.6.15 , phpMyAdmin 5.0.2 , MariaDB 10.4 , Redis 5.0.7 , Memcached 1.5.22 , CertBot 0.40.0

HTTP Site: http://bonheurgifts.in/

HTTPS site: https://bonheurgifts.in/

I searched and searched for solutions to redirect it but I can't find one, please help.

Also, the rewrite rule in the WebAdmin console is not working. It shows a 404 error when I try to save something.

I just want it to work properly.
When anybody types [bonheurgifts.in](http://bonheurgifts.in) and hits enter it should show the main site properly

Comment: maybe you can check a bit this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urnHwEQ2eAE&t=312s&ab_channel=LiteSpeedTechnologies , it's not exactly same env as OLS WP image, but it should give you idea for how to correctly setup vhost and map domain in listener.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP port is served by Nginx which will conflict with the OpenLiteSpeed port 80, you might probably install the package by accident. Please check if there's any Nginx service running with the command,

```
ps aux | grep -i nginx
```

If exist, stop it and remove the package.

```
systemctl stop nginx
apt-get remove nginx
```

The redirect/Rewrite is not working should be due to the same reason.

Comment: there is something running on my server . But when I try to stop it it asks for a password which I have no idea about. I tried my OLS console password but it does not work. then I uninstalled ngnix but still it does not change anything.

Comment: sudo/root is required to remove packages, just run sudo -s should help.  What's the output from the replied command, like ps aux | grep -i nginx?

Comment: this is the output for 
ps aux | grep -i nginx    https://imgur.com/a/Xy5lAVQ

Comment: Please tell me the time you are online here and please help me resolve this issue..I need to launch the site ASAP..LAst time it was working perfectly until I changed the domain name of the site.

Comment: It seems nginx is running, which is probably installed by you or any other user who has root access and not just because of the domain changing. You will need to remove the nginx package first, then restart openlitespeed web server.

Comment: i dit it..also added rewrite rules but nothing had changed ..it just now shows server not reachable.. Here is the htaccess file text https://justpaste.it/3dryo and this is the htaceess file http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=09788510049906013759

Comment: it seems working fine to me. Maybe you want to view it on an incognito browser